# How to get a default positioned element go under a fixed element while scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, fixed

I want the form element group to go down under the fixed element while scrolling but it isn't happening . When i scroll down , i'm expecting the fixed positioned element covers the element going up but instead it is covering as if it were a transparent element and getting mixed with the element going up. Help . Here is the Link :
https://codepen.io/tanveer_nihal/pen/xxZqNXw

```
 <https://codepen.io/tanveer_nihal/pen/xxZqNXw>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set this to your `#header` in css

```
background-color: white;
```

You think that it's not working because the you don't set any background so it's transparent. If you add a `background-color` you will see this.

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: @ysf Edited just now

Comment: I didn't understand what you just said